# How to prevent Dockerfile caching git clone

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile trying to package and deploy a web app to a container. The code of app fetches from git repository during Docker image building.
Here's the Dockerfile snapshot:

```
........
RUN git clone --depth=1 git-repository-url $GIT_HOME/
RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip
........
```

I want the docker do not cache the step of `RUN git clone --depth=1 git-repository-url $GIT_HOME/` so that the on-going updated on the the repository can be reflected on the Docker image building. Is it possible to a achieve that?

Answer (score 86):

Another workaround:

If you use GitHub (or gitlab or bitbucket too most likely) you can ADD the GitHub API's representation of your repo to a dummy location.

```
ADD https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/git/refs/heads/$BRANCH version.json
RUN git clone -b $BRANCH https://github.com/$USER/$REPO.git $GIT_HOME/
```

The API call will return different results when the head changes, invalidating the docker cache.

If you're dealing with private repos you can use [github's `x-oauth-basic` authentication scheme](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication) with a [personal access token](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) like so:

```
ADD https://$ACCESS_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/git/refs/heads/$BRANCH version.json
```

(thx @captnolimar for a suggested edit to clarify authentication)

Comment: Worked perfect for GitHub. Any example for private GitLab?

Comment: Nice solution. Heres how to do it for bitbucket.


`ADD https://[USER]:[PASS]@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/[ORG-NAME]/[REPO-NAME]/commit/[BRANCH] /info`

`RUN git clone --depth 1 --branch [BRANCH] https://[USER]:[PASS]@bitbucket.org/[ORG-NAME]/[REPO-NAME].git /repo`

I recommend creating a specific "Integration" user and using "App passwords" for bitbucket. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html Combine this with multi-stage build, and it seems like the perfect solution so far.

Comment: Hi @Ivan look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59685604/2992810

Comment: Do do it in a completely generic provider independent way, here's an option `ADD http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip /time.tmp`

Comment: As in 2020, the github api appears to have changed and the URL `https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/git/refs/heads/$BRANCH` doesn't work anymore, due to api updates? Please suggest the updated URL.

Comment: @HemantArora Hmm, what response are you getting? It seems to work for me: https://api.github.com/repos/dokku/dokku/git/refs/heads/master Are you certain that the user, repo, and branch are correct and visible to the authenticated user?

Comment: @HemantArora 
See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/troubleshooting#basic-authentication-errors
`On November 13, 2020 username and password authentication to the REST API and the OAuth Authorizations API were deprecated and no longer work.`
The solution given is to use curl to provide the authorization header.

Comment: For GitLab:
`ADD https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/repository/branches/$BRANCH_NAME/ version.json`

Comment: If like me you're on GitLab with access token, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59685604/11159476

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this same issue myself, and I just decided to use the `--no-cache` option when I build the image, rather than trying to single out the git repo.

```
docker build --no-cache -t my_image .
```

Comment: For my simple use case, this was the simplest/easiest of the proposed solutions. Thank you, @tomgsmith99.

Answer (score 17):

[Issue 1996](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1996) is not yet available, but you have the [following workaround](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1996#issuecomment-172606763):

```
FROM foo
ARG CACHE_DATE=2016-01-01
RUN git clone ...

docker build --build-arg CACHE_DATE=$(date) ....
```

That would invalidate cache after the `ARG CACHE_DATE` line  for every build.

Or:

```
ADD http://www.convert-unix-time.com/api?timestamp=now /tmp/bustcache
RUN git pull
```

That would also invalidate cache after this ADD line.

[Similar idea](http://dev.im-bot.com/docker-select-caching/):

> Add `ARG` command to your Dockerfile:
>
> ```
> # Dockerfile
> # add this and below command will run without cache
> ARG CACHEBUST=1
> ```
>
> When you need to rebuild with selected cache, run it with `--build-arg` option
>
> ```
> $ docker build -t your-image --build-arg CACHEBUST=$(date +%s) .
> ```
>
> then only layer below `ARG` command in Dockerfile will rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.
But it doesn't work for me as I use a cloud CaaS to build the Docker image. There's no way to pass docker arguments.

Comment: doesn't work for me. Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

Comment: @StephanRichter and https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/10682#issuecomment-178794901 ?

Answer (score 9):

for anyone who has this problem with Gitlab repositories:

Gitlab has this annoying branch id method when calling their API, the ID will appear under your repository name
[image]

```
# this will copy the last change from your brach and it'll invalidate the cache if there was a new change
ADD "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/repository/branches/master?private_token=${GIT_TOKEN}" /tmp/devalidateCache

# the actual clone
RUN git clone --depth=1 https://${GIT_USER}:${GIT_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/${git_file_uri} ${BASE_BUILD_PATH}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use github you can use github API to not cache specific RUN command.
You need to have jq installed to parse JSON: apt-get install -y jq

Example:

```
docker build --build-arg SHA=$(curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/Tencent/mars/commits' | jq -r '.[0].sha') -t imageName .
```

In Dockerfile (ARG command should be right before RUN):

```
ARG SHA=LATEST
RUN SHA=${SHA} \
    git clone https://github.com/Tencent/mars.git
```

or if you don't want to install jq

```
SHA=$(curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/Tencent/mars/commits' | grep sha | head -1)
```

If repository has new commits, git clone will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use:

```
ADD "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h" skipcache

RUN git reset --hard ~Whatever~
```

as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801213/8953378

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea of @anq , but the provided api is outdated, the latest api documentation is in [Get a reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/refs#get-a-reference)

use `https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/ref/heads/{ref}`

example `https://api.github.com/repos/wind8866/hello-react/git/ref/heads/main`

Answer (score -3):

For github private repos, you could also pass in your username and password:

`RUN git clone -b$BRANCH https://$USER:$PASSWORD@github.com/$USER/$REPO.git $GIT_HOME/`

Comment: I wouldn't like to pass my user password if I'm letting my admins clone just one repo.