# How to rebuild Docker image if its dependency in a remote git repo is updated?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I have a dependency which is cloned from a remote git repo, then built and inserted into my app:

```
RUN git clone git@remote_repo.git .
RUN build
```

Naturally this repo is being developed in parallel and is updated from time to time.

Is there a way to check if it has new changes during `docker-compose build` run and rebuild it if needed?

Comment: I think this question: [How to prevent Dockerfile caching git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996046/how-to-prevent-dockerfile-caching-git-clone) has some info which (maybe) could be applied to your `docker-compose` case.

Comment: Also, a solution which ignores the *rebuild it if needed* part of your question would be the `--no-cache` option