# Rebuild Docker images when its packages received (security) updates

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian

I have just changed a Dockerfile with a `RUN git clone ...` instruction such that it now can notice changes in the Git repository and rebuild accordingly. This has required working around Docker's normal caching mechanism.

I've chosen a mechanism that introduces an ARG that holds Git commit hash of the repository's head, as suggested [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1996). I've also taken notice of an alternative mechanism that copies a similar version "hash" by means of an `ADD` instruction, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996046/how-to-prevent-dockerfile-caching-git-clone).

The same Dockerfile also installs several (Debian) packages by means of `RUN apt-get install -y ...`. Therefore I am wondering: Are there similar workarounds for (partially) rebuilding a Docker image if any of the packages received (security) updates? Based on the aforementioned `ADD`-based workaround I could e.g. imagine something based on a web service that receives key/value pairs consisting of package names/version numbers and that returns an eligible "hash" in the case of pending (security) updates. Does such a specific component exist or are there more general best practices for covering such a use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is the biggest weakness that docker has not solved at all.

The usual workaround afaik is to rebuild the image from scratch nightly (on a build server?) and then auto promote it to production if the your tests run fine against it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ultimately had to adopt as well.

Comment: On some servers, I actually took the route that I pulled the image nightly and just add a layer with the latest security updates and then restart the app. That all packages up nicely in a systemd.unit and a cron job. See here for details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-15967?focusedCommentId=17485758&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17485758